# My "days consecutive" just reset to 1

Tags: support

Ok, I admit this is a foolish thing to care about, but I have been eyeballing the "days consecutively visited" for this site every day now for a few months.  Yesterday it said something like 71.  Today it says 1.

I'm 100% sure I didn't miss a day, since I know what it said yesterday, and viewing my profile requires that I'm logged in.

Is this a known bug?  Do I have any recourse?

Comment: You know that the "day" is counted in UTC, right? For example, I'm in CDT; if I had last logged in yesterday at 18:59 CDT, and the next time had been today at 19:01CDT, I would have "missed a day".

Comment: @Arturo: Good to know, but I'm sure I visited at least 5 times over the day.  I must have not ventured past the opening page yesterday, as Jeff suggested.

Comment: Oh, Fixee you missed the Fanatic badge :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Arturo noted, our day is from UTC 00:00:00 to UTC 23:59:59.

There are no known issues with the daily access code at this time.

Also, to be 'seen' at the site you must visit more than a public exterior page, e.g. not just the homepage.

Comment: I visit 5-10 times per day... my bookmark toolbar has google news, then math.SE, and I check both a few times per day.  Very often, I find a math topic that I'm interested in reading/answering, but perhaps yesterday for the first time in 71 days I didn't find anything interesting and therefore never ventured past the home page, not realizing this would reset my counter.  Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

I personally wouldn't worry too much about the Fanatic Badge, it is just not worth the effort.

I realized pretty early on that I will never get it, despite the fact that I spend a very large amount of time here each week.  I tend to have at least one day every two months with zero internet access, for one reason or another.  Either it is moving to a new city (which happened at the start of this summer, and will happen again at the end), traveling somewhere else (like this week), or just simple computer problems.

I understand that it is very disappointing to come so close, but is that badge really worth working for?  I would much rather get my gold badges from "Great Answer,"  "Great Question," "Populist" or "Ledgendary." (but none of these have happened yet to me!)

Comment: This is why they invented smartphones with 3G internet access. I think that apart for sleeping (and with my sleep that doesn't make it very long) I check the site every hour or so.

Comment: @Asaf: That's why they invented twelve-step programs...

Comment: @Arturo: Well... I have no choice ;-)

Comment: @Asaf: Read Jeff's post below.  I check the site every few hours too, but checking doesn't suffice... you have to do something more (which isn't clearly defined... probably on purpose).  I'm seriously tempted to just script this and come back in 71 days so I can pick up where I left off.

Comment: @Fixee: I usually read some questions, answers, comments, and I write comments, reply to comments, read replies to comments.